# How do I export a TypeScript ESM Module as an NPM package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json

Recently, I had to fork an open source NPM package that was built using TypeScript and exported using CommonJS. The package hasn't been maintained for a couple of years, so I had to update all of the dependencies, which made the code break.

One of the dependencies, [unified](https://github.com/unifiedjs), was being imported using `const unified = require("unified");` which is CommonJS syntax, but in a newer version of `unified` that I updated to, they started forcing `unified` to be imported using ESM syntax like `import { unified } from "unified"`. So I decided to convert my entire package to ESM.

I added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` and updated all of the code to use ESM style imports/exports, but now that I'm ready to publish the package, I'm confused on a couple of things.

The original developer had the project setup like this:

```
├── src/
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── options.ts
│   ├── toc.ts // where most of the code logic lives. This is the entry point to the application and the main function I want to export
│   └── ... // whole bunch of other typescript files
├── lib/
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   └── ... // this repeats for every typescript file in src/
├── dist/
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
└── └── package.json
```

In `tsconfig.json`, he had `"outDir": "lib",` so all of the TypeScript files inside `src/` get exported with their type stuff to the `lib` folder. That makes sense to me.

But what I'm confused on is what am I supposed to put in `src/index.ts`, `dist/index.js` and `index.d.ts` ?

This what the developer originally had:

**src/index.ts**

```
import { toc } from "./my-package";

export { CssClasses, Options } from "./options";
export * from "./types";
export { toc };

// Export `toc` as the default export
export default toc;

if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
  module.exports = Object.assign(module.exports.default, module.exports);
}
```

**dist/index.d.ts**

```
import toc from "@username/my-package";
export * from "@username/my-package";
export default toc;
```

**dist/index.js**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = require("@username/my-package");
```

**dist/package.json**

```
  "name": "@username/my-package",
  "version": "3.0.0",
// ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@username/my-package": "3.0.0"
  }
```

So my questions are:

1. What goes inside `dist/index.js` and `dist/index.d.ts` ? Do I just make a copy of those files from `lib` and paste them in `dist`?
2. To make my package fully ESM, What should I replace the `module.exports` lines with in `src/index.ts` and `dist/index.js` ?
3. Is there anything else I need to add to my `dist/package.json`, besides `"type": "module"`? Is it really that simple, that I only need 3 files in my distribution folder?

Comment: For your question #2, there are literally thousands of articles on how to write an ESM module.  You can start with using `import` and `export`, not `require()` and `module.exports` (which you seem to already know earlier in your question).

Comment: On question #1, you never put a TypeScript file in `dist`.  Neither the browser or nodejs can run TypeScript directly.  You compile TypeScript into regular Javascript and that's what your environment runs.  You have to configure the TypeScript compiler to produce the type of result you want (CommonJS or ESM module).